# how to access color from array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, colors

i'm trying to access the color listed in the array but not sure how to access ,i've search on google but no helping content find.

```
protected void DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string[] color=new string[] {"Azure","BlanchedAlmond","Black","Beige","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkOrange"}
        for(int i=0 ;i<color.Length;i++)
        {
            if(DropDownList7.SelectedIndex==i)
                Label11.ForeColor=Color.?;
        }
    }
```

how to access color from color Array to use it.

`Label11.ForeColor=Color.?;`

Comment: If you get that error you're not using my code, Check my code carefully. I'm using `Color[] colors` not `string[] color`, also don't edit errors to answers, just comment below them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `FromName` as below...

```
Label11.ForeColor=Color.FromName(color[i]);
```

But, I would recommend storing the colors in an array of `System.Drawing.Color` instead of magic strings. Or perhaps storing their hex representation such as "#000000"

Answer (score 1):

Store colors as `Color` object then you can access it easily, otherwise you may need to use [Color.FromName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
protected void DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color[] colors=new Color[] {Color.Azure, Color.BlanchedAlmond,...};
    for(int i=0 ;i<colors.Length;i++)
    {
        if(DropDownList7.SelectedIndex==i)
            Label11.ForeColor=colors[i];
    }
}
```

Just noted, you're looping through array and finding index which can be easily re written as

```
if(DropDownList7.SelectedIndex >=0 == DropDownList7.SelectedIndex < colors.Length)
    Label11.ForeColor=colors[DropDownList7.SelectedIndex];
```

Comment: +1 from me, this is the best solution: just don't use strings

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = Color.FromName("Gold");
```

in your case

```
var color = Color.FromName(color[DropDownList7.SelectedIndex]);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
label1.ForeColor = color[selectedIndex];
```

if you simply want the offset corresponding to the selected dropdown.

Comment: Considering this is a valid method for settings the color correctly in this scenario, you should comment when down voting please.

Comment: -1 The reason is simple. This line of code will never compile because `color` is an array of strings and the `ForeColor` property is a `struct`...there's no implicit conversion between structs and strings. At least not in the .NET Framework